# How to find Lazarus dependencies to run my project on a new computer?

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, lazarus

I have a program built using Lazarus.

I want to run this on a machine that has no Lazarus. Is this possible? If so, how do I determine the dependencies to put on the new computer?

NOTE: I'm not keen on making an installer or anything of this sort. I just want to run my program on a second machine without Lazarus.

Note: I need this to work on Ubuntu (i.e., development and deployment is on Ubuntu) for now but it may be Windows as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be keen on creating an installer, but at the very least you may have to consider creating a package for the target platform.

The documentation describes this process for several target platforms:

- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Deploying_Your_Application

Unfortunately, even cross platform technologies (like Java) have pre-requisites for the platform they are deployed onto. It is also notoriously difficult to have a solution that works on both Linux and Windows. This is why some technologies have their own package managers designed to be used once the base language install (platform specific part) has been completed.

Comment: @Marco Thank you for your reference. As an immediate requirement I'd like to just test my project on another Ubuntu machine (which is the same as mine). So I guess the .deb package is the way to go. Unfortunately the only link on your reference is from IBM and it seems broken. Do you know how this can be achieved without me having to install Lazarus on the second computer? Thanks!

Comment: @itsols This looks like your best bet. https://github.com/prof7bit/LazPackager Apologies, I'm not a Lazarus user.

Comment: Yes, it seems like your option is the best so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get build-dep lazarus-ide

or

> sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtk-2.0 imagemagick imagemagick-common liba52-0.7.4-dev libasound2-dev libatk1.0-dev libavahi-client-dev libavahi-common-dev libcaca-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libdbus-1-dev libdca-dev libdrm-dev libdts-dev libexpat1-dev libflac-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgtk2.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev liblqr-1-0 libmad0-dev libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libmikmod2 libmikmod2-dev libmodplug-dev libogg-dev libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-dev libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libslang2-dev libsm-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxau-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxshmfence-dev libxxf86vm-dev mesa-common-dev po-debconf quilt x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev